# Function to verify if first OR last item in array are equal to a certain number

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am trying to write a function to check if an array contains a specific number at the first or last position of the array.

All of the `console.log` examples there should print `true`. The way its printing I don't think I should be writing to `console.log` in my function. I can't get them all to show `true`.

```js
function checkForNumber(arr, num) {
  if (arr[0] === num) {
    //console.log(true) removed
    return true
  } else if (arr.slice(-1)[0] === num) {
    //console.log(true) removed
    return true
  } else
    return false;
}
console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 4) === true);
console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 3) === true);
console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 2) === false);
console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 13) === false);
```

Comment: `if (arr[0] === num && arr[arr.length - 1] == num) {console.log(true); return true;} else return false;`

Comment: do you care about empty or single element arrays?

Comment: Do you mean `OR` instead of `AND`? None of your test cases have the same number in the first and last position of the array.

Comment: All your test cases return `true`. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: **The way its printing i don't think i should be writing to console.log in my function.** Those lines are commented out. You shouldn't edit the question to include the solution, it needs to show the original problem, so that the answers make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
function checkForNumber(arr, num) {
  return arr[0] === num || arr[arr.length - 1] === num;
}
console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 4) === true);
console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 3) === true);
console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 2) === false);
console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 13) === false);
```

`if (condition) return true` and similar are anti-patterns. If the function is a predicate (i.e. returning a boolean value), just return the result of the logical operation.

Answer (score 1):

In your **[first version of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52105459/1)** you had `console.log(true);` instead of `return true;` and this was wrong.

```js
function checkForNumber(arr, num)
{
 if(arr[0] === num)
 {
  //console.log(true);
  return true;
 }
 else if (arr[arr.length-1] === num)
 {
  //console.log(true);
  return true;
 }
 else return false;
}
console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 4) === true);
console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 3) === true);
console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 2) === false);
console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 13) === false);
```

You could write too:

```js
function checkForNumber(arr, num)
{
 return  arr[0] === num || arr[arr.length - 1] === num;
}

console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 4) === true);
console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 3) === true);
console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 2) === false);
console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 13) === false);
```

But your **[second code version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52105459/2)** is correct and if you write it on this way:

```
function checkForNumber(arr, num)
{
    return  arr[0] === num || arr.slice(-1)[0] === num;
}
```

then it is one symbol even shorter than:

```
function checkForNumber(arr, num)
{
    return  arr[0] === num || arr[arr.length - 1] === num;
}
```

Comment: An answer with code but no explanation of what was wrong and how you fixed it is not a high quality answer.

Comment: @Barmar, you are right but the lastest answer with most of points does not have any explanation about what was wrong and how it was fixed. The explanation there is about something else.

Comment: Who knows why people vote the way they do? Don't get hung up on it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution fully implemented that I suggested in the comments.

```js
function checkForNumber(arr, num) {
  if (arr[0] === num || arr[arr.length - 1] === num) {
    return true
  } else
    return false;
}

console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 4));
console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 3));
console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 2));
console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 13));
console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 4], 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is enough, right?
Cheers!

```
function checkForNumber(arr, num)
{
    // for OR
    return ((arr[0] === num) || (arr[arr.length-1] === num));
    // for AND
    // return ((arr[0] === num) && (arr[arr.length-1] === num));
}
console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 4) === true);
console.log(checkForNumber([3, 2, 5, 4], 3) === true);
console.log(checkForNumber([0, 4, 4, 8], 2) === false);
console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 13) === false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing this while editing, but i replaced the console.log(true) inside the function with return true. This solved my question.

Correct Code here again:

```
function checkForNumber(arr, num) {
  if (arr[0] === num) {
     //console.log(true) removed
     return true
   } else if (arr.slice(-1)[0] === num) {
     //console.log(true) removed
     return true
   } else
  return false;
 }
console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 4) === true);
console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 3) === true);
console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 2) === false);
console.log(checkForNumber([4, 2, 5, 3], 13) === false);
```